# CLLocation may not respond to setDistanceFilter

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I'm a newbie to programming for iPhone, I'm following along [this](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide) book.
I'm stuck at the example in Chapter 4, Delegation and Core Location.

Here's the code I've written so far:
WhereamiAppdelegate.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

    @interface WhereamiAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
        UIWindow *window;
        CLLocation *locationManager;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

    @end
```

And here is the implementation file:
I have only included the changes that I've made.
The entire file is [here](http://pastebin.com/ncwcgmd5).

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Create location manager.
        locationManager = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%@",newLocation);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't find loaction %@",error);
}
```

XCode gives me a warning that says CLLocation may not respond to setDistanceFilter and other similar warnings.
I am clueless here, I have followed the book line to line.
I think that I haven't implemented a necessary protocol or something. 
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I should proceed further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class [`CLLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) is not the same as [`CLLocationManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html). The former represents one location, while the latter is the manager class that handles configuring location updates for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Things like setDistanceFilter: are undocumented parts of system APIs. They may change without warning in future versions of iOS (any), and they also disqualify your app from being in AppStore, but if you're fine with that, no problem... if Apple really wanted to hide those things, they wouldn't be findable by just making a for-loop on a method-table.

BTW, the difference between CLLocation and CLLocationManager is irrelevant for your situation, because the code actually runs and does the right thing, so, you are sending the correct messages to the correct objects.